# 2003 Honda CR-V AWD - intermittently Flashing Drive light

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission

My Wife's 2003 Honda CR-V's Drive light in the cluster occasionally starts flashing. The manual states that this means that the transmission requires service, but it doesn't do it all the time, and the transmission is not showing any signs of distress (slow shifts, not being able to engage any specific gear, increased noise, ect).

What generally causes this? Bad sensor? Just trying to figure out if I need to budget for a trip to the stealership in the next

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you have a bad 4<sup>th</sup> gear pressure switch. It seems to be a common problem. I had worked at a Honda dealer for 20 years, and replaced a lot of them.

Comment: Any idea how much this costs to fix and if this would be something we should do before the transmission presents any symptoms?